# About AsyncTask updating UI thread with dialog

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, dialog, queue

I'm developing an Android app that has a basic structure: activity that requests some action from AsyncTask implementer. The implementer has 3 custom methods that should be able to update UI thread with a Dialog and a postExecute() that should update UI thread with a failuer Dialog if an exception is thrown. Here are some questions:

1. Where should I create the Dialog object? In the activity class or the AsyncTask implementer? What general guidelines should I follow?
2. Can I update UI thread with a Dialog without waiting for postExecute()?
3. How can I update UI thread with a picture? Should I create a custom Dialog or is there an easier way?
4. If the updates - as dialogs with pictures - come one after another, in a sequence how should I deal with it? Should I create some kind of queue? How would you do it?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)There's a couple of different ways you can do this.  But personally I usually create the dialog in onPreExecute of the AsyncTask, so that the UI for the task is completely self contained.

2)Yes.  You can do it in onProgressUpdate.  doInBackground should call publishProgress() which will cause onProgressUpdate to be called on the UI thread.

3)Too few details-  where do you want the picture?  In an existing image view?  On top of the current layout? If you just want to display it in a dialog box, an AlertDialog with custom layout would probably work.

4)Depends on the app.  Do you want the user to see all the images, or is it ok to miss images in the middle if a new one is sent?

Comment: Thank you for the help Gebe. As for (3) - I want to create create a dialog box with a picture in the center on the screen that would offer either to keep the image (and save it to the database) or discard it. As for (4) - I only want one dialog at a time, but I do not want to stop the execution of the ASynTask implementer that returns the pictures - I think that would help performance if I would not block the AsynTask as the dialog is show, but for that I need some kind of temporary storage - what would you advice on these two?

Comment: For 3, an AlertDialog with an ImageView centered in it would work pretty well for you.